# Data in DbContext DbSet different than Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a DbContext called ProjectContext which has a `DbSet` called Cart that I pass values into:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    ProjectContext _db = new ProjectContext();

    public void AddToCart(Video toAdd, Customer CurUser)
    {
        var CartItem = new Cart
        {
            CustomerID = CurUser.CustomerID,
            Item = toAdd.Title,
            Count = 1,
            Price = 1.00m
        };
        _db.Carts.Add(CartItem);
        _db.SaveChanges();

    }

}

public class Cart
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Basically a customer can have many different cart records with the same `CustomerID`. Everything is fine in the actual database and all correct records are added. The problem is that in the actual `DbContext` the first data record I insert for each customer gets repeated. So when I view the model in my View the first record for each customer just repeats for however many actual records there are for that `CustomerID`.

I can see while debugging that the records in Cart do in fact repeat in the `DbSet`, although they do not in the actual database.

I've never heard of anything like this and really have no idea what the problem is, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

When I query my carts table in SQL Server I see this:

```
5   shutter island  2   1.00
5   billy madison   2   1.00
5   superbad        1   1.00
```

When I view in a View I see this:

```
Item           Count     Price 
shutter island     2     1.00  
shutter island     2     1.00  
shutter island     2     1.00
```

Code where I pass my model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   IEnumerable model =(from r in _cartdb.Carts
            where r.CustomerID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
            select r);

   return View(model);
}
```

Code in the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCVideoProject.Models.Cart>
<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Remove Item", "RemoveItem", new { custID = item.CustomerID, toRemove = item.Item })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I can see when debugging that the `DbSet` called Carts which I use has the repeating records so I don't think the View is the problem.

Comment: Can you post the code where you output to the view? Also where you pass the model to the view?

Comment: original edited to respond to your comment, thanks.

Comment: And the code in your view?

Comment: So to be clear, it is right in the DB, wrong in the return from `from r in _cartdb.Carts where r.CustomerID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId select r);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Cart` entity must have a *unique* primary key. `CustomerID` is not unique and EF just always takes the first record it can find for one specific value. So I would introduce a `CartId` field.